# How to place a heading on the endnotes in Libre Office Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, footnote

I have a document in Libre Office Writer that has around a hundred endnotes -- or technically, footnotes, with the "End of document" position setting (*). These notes begin at the top of a new page near the end of the document, and run for several pages, as desired. But I'd also like a heading/title on that page, e.g., "Endnotes" to set off that part of the document. I've played around with line breaks, page breaks, and trying to add a new section, all to no avail.

How can I add a header to the starting page of the footnotes/endnotes part of my Libre Office Writer document?

(*) The workflow I'm setting up has source text in Markdown files, converted to Libre Office via Pandoc. While endnotes are what I really want, extended Markdown doesn't have that, supporting footnotes only (as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways. The easiest one is some sort of workaround: Add a header to the Endnotes page.

1. Open the Styles panel using <kbd>F11</kbd>;
2. Select page styles using the button above the styles list;
3. Look for the "Endnote" page style, right-click and "Modify";
4. On the "Header" tab, check "Header on" (if your endnotes take several pages, you may want to uncheck "Same content on first page" to prevent your heading from appearing on every endnotes page.

The second approach allows to manually edit the Endnotes page and to put content after the Endnotes pages (Thanks to [oweng from ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/heading-for-endnotes-page/4402)): It mainly consists of two steps.

1. First, manually add a document section where the endnotes will be collected;
2. Then, Trigger a re-arrangement of existing endnotes.

Let's assume you have a document with some text containing endnotes and an endnotes section at the end of the document. Do the following:

1. Go to the end of your contents section;
2. Insert a manual break -> Page break with Page Style: Endnote
3. An **empty** page with page style "Endnote" will appear after your new page break; modify that empty page at your will, add headings and so on.
4. Now, re-arrange the endnotes to appear on your new Endnotes page:

   1. Highlight your document content including any content on your new Endnotes page that should appear before your endnotes;
   2. Menu "Insert" -> "Sections" -> "Footnotes/Endnotes" tab -> check "Collect at end of section".
5. Now, the endnotes should appear on your new custom Endnotes page.

Comment: Thanks for this (and finding the ask.libreoffice answer). I can get the first method working. The second method does work for actual endnotes. But unfortunately it doesn't work analogously for my case where I've really got footnotes (coming out of Markdown source).